# django create relation between 2 database entries

Tags: sql, django

Apologies if the title is not accurate but I am fairly new in Django and I am still trying to understand the basics.

I have create a model where I can create a server name. I have a second model where I create one or more interfaces to associated to each server.

What I want is to connect one interface of one server to another interface of another server. I have a feeling it has something to do with `ForeignKey` but I would not know how to implement that.

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    interface   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hostname    = models.ForeignKey(to='NetworkDevice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.interface

    class Meta():
        ordering = ('hostname',)


class NetworkDevice(models.Model):
    hostname    = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


    class Meta():
        ordering = ('hostname',)

    def __str__(self):
```

```
SERVER1              SERVER2
  |_ eth0 <-----> eth0_|
  |_ eth1 <-----> eth1_|
```

Comment: What do you mean by one interface of one server? Is it that you have a server that has many interfaces?

Comment: description updated with diagram :)

Comment: Read the documentation to do that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/